# TcpListener not accepting client

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I have this web server I tried to make using TcpListener, but it won't accept about half of the requests I made. It simply hangs on `AcceptTcpClient` when the request is made, also it behaves the same on any port.

```
this.main = new Thread(() =>
{
     while (this.running)
     {

         TcpClient c = this.t.AcceptTcpClient();
         new Task(() =>
         {
             handleClient(c);
         }).Start();

     }
});
this.main.Start();
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the  new Thread and  new Task this code works just fine. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
public void Start()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server started...");

    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 1234);
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            HandleClient(client);
        })).Start();
    }
}

 private void HandleClient(TcpClient client)
 {
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII) { AutoFlush = true };
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII);

    string inputLine = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("The client with name " + " " + inputLine + " is conected");

}
```